# How to select multiple URLs wiht request_uri

Tags: php

I'm having php script that deals with thousands of queries starting  just like (i.e. http://localhost:1234/browse.php?cat=2) so I don't want to write thousands of URLs in an array to deal with if and else condition such as below,
Please guide me how can i make it possible to use "?" sign in my url to distinguish between what command to process if url contains "?" sign.
I used "/browse.php?*" in code as shown in below example but it's not working for me still...Please guide because I'm new in php and search and lot regarding this answer but unable to find a single authentic answer for it, thanks

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],array('/browse.php','/browse.php?*')))
{
echo "<Something Like this 1>";
}
elseif ($url == "")
{
echo "<Something Like this 2>";
};
```

Comment: Try `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` or even `echo $_GET['cat']`. See info about [PHP $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [PHP $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` would only check for a full match here and is not appropriate for what you are trying to do. PHP has many [String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) you should look at.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') !== false) {
    //URL has '?' mark
}
else{
    //URL has no '?' mark
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are only concerned with the `cat` URL search parameter?  If so, you can access this parameter in your `browse.php` script using the `$_GET` array:

```
<?php
    if (array_key_exists('cat', $_GET)) {
        echo "cat parameter: {$_GET['cat']}"; // display ?cat=value
    } else {
        echo 'No cat URL parameter'; // ?cat was not in the URL
    }
?>
```

`http://localhost:1234/browse.php`  ->  No cat URL parameter

`http://localhost:1234/browse.php?cat=57890`  ->  cat parameter: 57890